# How to add scrollable background image in sliding fragments in android?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app which is having 7 tabbed (slidable) fragments. I want to add a single scrollable background to these fragments. Searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution to this.

I want to have the same effect as that of a home screen in any launcher - When you swipe through different views the background also scrolls accordingly.

An example would be:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uP91iN04kyc (@ 1:17)

Pointers on how to do that are also enough.

I was thinking if we can have an image as background and set the x offfset and width of the image for every tabbed fragment, then we can achieve the same effect. Not sure if that will be the right approach or it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ImageView behind your pager.

Set its (ImageView) right margin to negative value (so the width of the image is greater than width of the screen)

Then register listener for pager scroll and set image view translateX accordinally.

Voila, scrolling background image.

Comment: Could you please go more in depth @sidon?